# Changing Page Based On a Variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to make a simple html page that returns a different animation (stored in different HTML documents, although this can be changed I thought it was best for cleanliness) based on the return of variable "*response*". I have been having issues with this simple script to return my desired results, and I havent found many relevant results online (inb4 LMGTFY). I know that the *response* variable is being created as desired as it was printing the number chosen, athough now it seems intermittent as to when it likes to print.

Does anyone have advice on an effective way to script this?

Cheers,
Matt

(current HTML is as follows, I havent implemented any CSS or external scripts otherwise)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">        
    <title>Fielder's Choice Spinner</title>        
    <meta name="description" content="Instore spinner for FC">
    <meta name="author" content="Matthew Davis">        
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--ill just leave this here-->

    <script language="JavaScript">
        var response = (function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
            min = Math.ceil(1);
            max = Math.floor(1000);
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive 
        })();

        document.write(response)

        if (response > 900) {
            window.location.replace("win.html")
        } 
        if (response < 900){
            window.location.replace("lose.html")
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect to the html page or load the content? How does the content look like?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. It's working but the response is only visible some miliseconds because you're reloading the page when you redirect to `win.html` or `loose.html`

Comment: @doomenik it is a square aspect html animation made in Adobe Animate that I would idealy like to make to fit the size of the display, so it probably wouldnt matter either way. It is just easier for me to keep files organised if I scale this to have more outcomes

Comment: @raul.vila what I dont understant is why either of the pages arent being redirected to with the current implementation. The URL should chance to either ...\win.html or ...\lose.html based on the result, yet it remains on the same page.

Comment: @M.Davis The only corner case I find is when `response == 900`, in that case no redirect is executed.

Comment: And I assume that is fixed with >= and <=?

Comment: @M.Davis You can use one of those (if you use both, the second would be redundant) or an `if-else` statement. (note: if you want an user to receive a notification of your comment, add @ followed by the user's name. Otherwise it's almost impossible to know about it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the hashtag.  It used to be a secret character for programmers before Twitter adopted it.

example: if you redirect to "win.html#756", then win.html can read that number, with window.location.hash
To remove the hash sign itself you can use .substr(1)

index.html (I changed it a little, take away what you want)

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onload = function() {
      var response = function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(1);
        max = Math.floor(1000);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive 
      };
      var myresponse = response();
      if (myresponse > 900) {
        window.location.replace("win.html#" + myresponse);
      } 
      if (myresponse < 900) {
        window.location.replace("lose.html#" + myresponse);
      }
    }
</script>
```

win.html (dito for lose.html, except the message)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fielder's Choice Spinner - WIN</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script language="JavaScript">
    window.onload = function() {
      var myresponse = window.location.hash.substr(1);
      document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = myresponse;
    }

  </script>
  <style>#data { color: red; font-size: 18px;}</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">YOU WON --- Your score is: <span id="data"></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```